# Embed Twilio Flex into a custom application

Tags: twilio-flex

I have written a custom application and would like to be able to offer Twilio Flex as a plugin.  I see that they have integrated their Flex Agent with CRMs like Salesforce.  Is there a guide or documentation on how to do this with a custom written app?

Comment: were you able to get an answer to your query or is this still open?

Comment: i have added a github repo that demonstrates the approach, hope its useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by

- Creating an iframe in your custom app that points to your flex url (https://flex.twilio.com if you are using hosted flex)
- rate flex plugin with your required features
- Use postMessage to implement the communication between your flex plugin and your custom app

Here is a sample repo that shows how to implement click to dial from a custom app using above method https://github.com/abhijitmehta/flexClickToDialCRMIframe